# not getting image from css background:url

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

The image doesn't show up to the index.html

```
<div id="headerwrap">
  <h1>Make your landing pagelook really good.</h1>      
</div><!-- /headerwrap -->
```

CSS

```
#headerwrap {
    background: url(../img/bbblur.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding-top: 200px;
    background-attachment: relative;
    background-position: center center;
    min-height: 650px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

previously it was working it shows the image when i preview it,
then i add a few codes then i preview it agian, its messed up, then i tried to undo my move, but still it doesn't show the image

Comment: Check the URL. I tried and worked http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/C93Lh/

Comment: Where is the location of the css file in relation to the index file?